# What does it mean to have different tracert result?

Tags: networkx

Our company has network issue and had some test since last couple of months.
It was super slow last Jan. but it got better this month. Network team didn't take any action and nothing changed. But when we compare tracert results, it seems that something must have been changed.

** tracert 1 month ago
  1     *       44 ms    66 ms  172.21.64.1
  2     *       65 ms    66 ms  172.21.64.254
  3   286 ms   272 ms   293 ms  172.30.247.121
  4   277 ms   267 ms   299 ms  192.168.254.233
  5     *      262 ms   287 ms  192.168.253.113
  6   321 ms   310 ms   271 ms  10.245.124.33
  7   308 ms   311 ms   294 ms  10.245.124.9
  8   268 ms   270 ms   303 ms  10.245.64.19

**tracert today
  1     3 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  172.21.64.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  172.21.64.254
  3   262 ms   262 ms   262 ms  172.30.247.121
  4   262 ms   273 ms     *     192.168.254.233
  5   265 ms   266 ms   263 ms  192.168.253.113
  6   266 ms   275 ms   302 ms  10.245.124.33
  7   289 ms   287 ms   280 ms  10.245.124.9
  8   269 ms   267 ms   263 ms  10.245.64.19

I'm not good at network nor couldn't find related topics from Google.
Could this be an evidence that some optimization or configuration could have been made?
Any kinds of view will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: These two traceroutes are not significantly different. They both show no packet loss (or packet loss below the ability to measure) and about 270ms round trip times.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, David. As replied to Richard's comment, would it be possible to have faster 2 hopes without any action or workaround?

Comment: You are misreading the traceroute. The traceroute does not suggest the first and second hops are any slower. If they were, the eighth hop would be slower too (since traffic to it has to go through the first two hops) and it's not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first and second hop routers response time is much better, but overall, the other routers area only slightly faster. These numbers are way too high. Anything over a 100 ms is too high for my liking. I would look at the 3rd hop, 172.30.247.121. That is where the slow down starts. The rest of the trip doesn't add much to the average, so they are ok.

I would look into that router and see if it is just too small for the traffic that it routes. Maybe it needs an update, maybe it needs a reboot, or maybe there is just too much traffic using it. It could have some odd Quality of Service setup that is slowing ICMP. A tracert is just a 32-byte ICMP ping that sets its "time-to-live" to "1" and increments each time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Richard. I'm not sure if first 2 hopes can be improved this much without any action. May I have your opinion?

Comment: The first two hops are fine. It is the third hop that is the slowdown. For an intranet router, that is really slow. Is that a site to site VPN starting at that third hop?

Comment: You are both misreading the traceroute. It does *not* show that any of the first three hops are slow. If a hop is slow by some number of milliseconds, then all traffic that has to take that hop will be slower by that same number of milliseconds. There is clear evidence in the traceroute that the eighth hop is the same in both traceroutes, therefore the traceroute does *not* suggest that any earlier hop has gotten slower.

Comment: Just imagine that hop 3 is adding about 250 ms while everything else is taking very little time, like 10 ms or less. Each hop is a separate ping request, so you won't see a perfect accumulation of time between the hops, but generally speaking, the 250 ms added at the third hop would make sense. For instance, lets say that hop 3 was 10,000 ms and hop 8 was 10,018 ms. And, in the second tracert, hop 8 was 10,014. You could argue that the last hop was about the same in both traces, therefore there isn't a problem. But, I would contend that hop 3 at 10,000 ms would be a problem.